# Callback events from .NET dll in Delphi application

Tags: c#, delphi, event-handling, portable-class-library, class-library

I'm trying to work with Proximity API in Delphi application over class library written on C#. Currently the device initialisation works fine, but i have no any idea how to back something from Proximity device events(DeviceArrived, DeviceDeparted). Here is my code:

**C# part**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Networking.Proximity;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace hsProximity
{
    [ComVisible(true), Guid("B6597243-2CC4-475B-BF78-427BEFE77346"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IHSCallbackHandler
    {
        void DeviceArrived(String AMessage);
    }

    [ComVisible(true), Guid("81C99F84-AA95-41A5-868E-62FAC8FAC263"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IHSProximityInterface
    {
        bool doInitialise(out String AMessage);
        void SetHandler(IHSCallbackHandler handler);
        void doGetUID(out String AUID);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ComVisible(true)]
    public class MainClass : IHSProximityInterface
    {
        public ProximityDevice proximityDevice;
        public List<NdefRecord> recordList;
        public String mUID = "";


        private IHSCallbackHandler handler;
        public void SetHandler(IHSCallbackHandler handler) 
        { 
            this.handler = handler; 
        }

        public void doGetUID(out String AUID)
        {
            AUID = mUID;
        }

        public bool doInitialise(out String AMessage)
        {
            recordList = new List<NdefRecord>();
            proximityDevice = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

            if (proximityDevice != null)
            {
                proximityDevice.DeviceArrived += ProximityDeviceArrived;
                proximityDevice.DeviceDeparted += ProximityDeviceDeparted;
                proximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", MessageReceivedHandler);
                AMessage = "Proximity device initialized. ID: " + proximityDevice.DeviceId;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                AMessage = "Failed to initialize proximity device.";
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void ProximityDeviceArrived(ProximityDevice sender)
        {
            //mCardStatusMsg = "Proximate device arrived.";
        }

        public void ProximityDeviceDeparted(ProximityDevice sender)
        {
            //mCardStatusMsg = "Proximate device departed.";
            mUID = "";
        }

        public void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
        {
            recordList.Clear();
            mUID = ParseNDEF(message);
            handler.DeviceArrived(mUID);
        }
```

**Part of TLB file**

```
uses Winapi.Windows, mscorlib_TLB, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Win.StdVCL, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.OleServer, Winapi.ActiveX;


const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  hsProximityMajorVersion = 1;
  hsProximityMinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_hsProximity: TGUID = '{DEB4779B-F6A7-37F2-8A63-1A2F99A22A73}';

  IID_IHSCallbackHandler: TGUID = '{B6597243-2CC4-475B-BF78-427BEFE77346}';
  IID_IHSProximityInterface: TGUID = '{81C99F84-AA95-41A5-868E-62FAC8FAC263}';
  CLASS_MainClass: TGUID = '{0333D76F-F345-3085-9F00-F816654CC89C}';
  IID__NdefRecord: TGUID = '{7C5F471E-68F8-3065-888E-95AB112B35B6}';
  CLASS_NdefRecord: TGUID = '{9F2A8192-94F9-3D0C-AD5F-D05D769DEF4B}';
type

  IHSCallbackHandler = interface;
  IHSProximityInterface = interface;
  _NdefRecord = interface;
  _NdefRecordDisp = dispinterface;

  MainClass = IHSProximityInterface;
  NdefRecord = _NdefRecord;

  IHSCallbackHandler = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{B6597243-2CC4-475B-BF78-427BEFE77346}']
    function DeviceArrived(const AMessage: WideString): HResult; stdcall;
  end;


  IHSProximityInterface = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{81C99F84-AA95-41A5-868E-62FAC8FAC263}']
    function doInitialise(out AMessage: WideString; out pRetVal: WordBool): HResult; stdcall;
    function SetHandler(const handler: IHSCallbackHandler): HResult; stdcall;
  end;


  _NdefRecord = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{7C5F471E-68F8-3065-888E-95AB112B35B6}']
  end;


  _NdefRecordDisp = dispinterface
    ['{7C5F471E-68F8-3065-888E-95AB112B35B6}']
  end;

  CoMainClass = class
    class function Create: IHSProximityInterface;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IHSProximityInterface;
  end;

 CoNdefRecord = class
    class function Create: _NdefRecord;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): _NdefRecord;
  end;
```

**Delphi part**

```
type
  THandler = class(TObject, IUnknown, IHSCallbackHandler)
  private
    FRefCount: Integer;
  protected
    function DeviceArrived(const AMessage: WideString): HResult; stdcall;

    function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  public
    property RefCount: Integer read FRefCount;
  end;
...
FProximity : IHSProximityInterface;
...
    procedure TFormMenu.TestProximityDllBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vUID : WideString;
  vMessage : WideString;
  vInitResult : WordBool;
begin
  if (FProximity <> nil) then begin
    OleCheck(FProximity.doGetUID(vUID));
    hsinfo(vUID);
  end else begin
    if (not Assigned(FProximity)) then begin
      FProximity := CreateComObject(CLASS_MainClass) as IHSProximityInterface;
    end;

    OleCheck(FProximity.doInitialise(vMessage, vInitResult));
    hsinfo(vMessage);

    FHandler := THandler.Create();
    OleCheck(FProximity.SetHandler(FHandler));
  end;
end;

function THandler.DeviceArrived(const AMessage: WideString): HResult;
begin
  showmessage(AMessage);
  result := 0;
end;
```

So currently doInitialise works fine and back me device ID, DeviceArrived also works but no any reacion from Delphi application side. Can somebody help what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have neglected error checking. Next step is to wrap all calls to functions that return `HRESULT` in `OIeCheck`. You also fail to return a value from `DeviceArrived`. The compiler will warn you about that. Are you ignoring compiler hints and warnings? Don't do that. This total disregard for error handling makes me suspect you are not familiar with COM. You should put that right too.

Comment: Hello. I understand you about DeviceArrived, it's already fixed, but still no any result on Delphi side. Also you have right about my experience in this question) Can you please explain more deep what i should fix for to have correct callback from dll to delphi part?

Comment: As I explained, you need to check return values for errors. Wrap them in `OleCheck`.

Comment: Sorry but not clear where to check return values if callback function never calls? Events works fine on dll side but can't call delphi procedure from dll. Or you mean use OleCheck inside dll when i use callback function?

Comment: Every single time you call a function that returns an HRESULT, check the return value. You don't do this even once.

Comment: I have updated my first post. Now you can see that i'm using OleCheck, but still no any callback to Delphi and no any errors. On dll side events is works because i store result in mUID variable and i can get it over doGetUID(out String AUID) procedure

Comment: Good. Next step is to debug the C# code to work out why the event doesn't fire. By the way, it's S_OK rather than 0. Same value, but S_OK reads better for obv reasons

Comment: You mean analyse what return handler.DeviceArrived(mUID);?

Comment: I mean debug your C# code. If you don't know how to attach a debugger then use trace debugging.

Comment: I'm writing program on Windows 7 machine, and test it on Windows 8.1 tablet, proximity device available only there))

Comment: So use trace debugging. Far more important than solving this specific problem is learning fundamental debugging skills.

Answer (score 0):

I have bit restyled my code. So here is solution which works like i want.

**C# part**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.Networking.Proximity;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;

namespace hsProximity
{
    public delegate void cbUID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string AStr);
    public delegate void cbState(int AStatus);

    [ComVisible(true), Guid("81C99F84-AA95-41A5-868E-62FAC8FAC263"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IHSProximityInterface
    {
        bool doInitialise(Int32 cbUIDPtr, Int32 cbStatePtr, out String AMessage);
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ComVisible(true)]
    public class MainClass : IHSProximityInterface
    {
        public ProximityDevice proximityDevice;
        public List<NdefRecord> recordList;
        IntPtr ptr;
        cbUID callbackUID;
        cbState callbackState;

        public bool doInitialise(Int32 cbUIDPtr, Int32 cbStatePtr, out String AMessage)
        {
            recordList = new List<NdefRecord>();
            proximityDevice = ProximityDevice.GetDefault();

            ptr = new IntPtr(cbUIDPtr);
            callbackUID = (cbUID)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(cbUID));

            ptr = new IntPtr(cbStatePtr);
            callbackState = (cbState)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(cbState));

            if (proximityDevice != null)
            {
                proximityDevice.DeviceArrived += ProximityDeviceArrived;
                proximityDevice.DeviceDeparted += ProximityDeviceDeparted;
                proximityDevice.SubscribeForMessage("NDEF", MessageReceivedHandler);
                AMessage = "Proximity device initialized. ID: " + proximityDevice.DeviceId;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                AMessage = "Failed to initialize proximity device.";
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void ProximityDeviceArrived(ProximityDevice sender)
        {
            callbackState(1);
        }

        public void ProximityDeviceDeparted(ProximityDevice sender)
        {
            callbackState(0);
        }

        public void MessageReceivedHandler(ProximityDevice sender, ProximityMessage message)
        {
            recordList.Clear();
            callbackUID(ParseNDEF(message));
        }
    }
}
```

**Delphi part**

```
FProximity : IHSProximityInterface;
...
procedure TFormMenu.TestProximityDllBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  vMessage : WideString;
  vInitResult : WordBool;
begin
  if Assigned(FProximity) then exit;

  if (not Assigned(FProximity)) then begin
    FProximity := CreateComObject(CLASS_MainClass) as IHSProximityInterface;
  end;

  if Assigned(FProximity) then begin
    FProximity.doInitialise(LongInt(@NDEFReceived), LongInt(@DeviceStatusChanges), vMessage, vInitResult);
    log(vMessage, 'NFC');
  end else begin
    log('Can''t create proximity class', 'NFC');
  end;
end;

procedure NDEFReceived(AMsg: PChar); stdcall;
begin
  log(AMsg, 'NFC');
end;

procedure DeviceStatusChanges(AStatus: integer); stdcall;
begin
  if (AStatus = 0) then begin
    log('Proximity device departed.', 'NFC');
  end else begin
    log('Proximity device arrived.', 'NFC');
  end;
end;
```